# How to change my mouse cursor when my mouse hover on specified area of my control? using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-2.0

I think my title pretty much says everything about my problem. But let us take a little deeper.

My problem is:-

I have this list of rectangles with X,Y, Width and Height whenever my mouse hover on the specified coordinates and area. I want my cursor to be changed to hand or something. But my Code doesn't seem to take effect for the previous rectangle areas but it does work for the last rectangle area in the list. Is there any workarounds you can lead me with

```
    void MouseChanger(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        RectangleF[] allRectangles = new RectangleF[aListDrawings.Count];
        aListDrawings.CopyTo(allRectangles);

        if (allRectangles.Length == 0)
            return;
        RectangleF currentSelected = RectangleF.Empty;

        foreach (RectangleF rec in allRectangles)
        {

            float Xm = e.X;
            float Ym = e.Y;
            RectangleF current = GetOffsetRectangle(rec);

            if (((Xm >= current.X) && (Xm <= (current.X + current.Width))) && ((Ym >= current.Y) && (Ym <= (current.Y + current.Width))))
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }

        }

    }
```

As you can see on the parameter the MouseEventArgs is going to be supplied to this method during the MouseMove Event. Thank you very much

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! Also have a look at [`Rectangle.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.contains%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - The actual error is in the else clause. Delete it and set a flag in the if; check this after the loop..!

Comment: I use break on the if clause. Thank you very much @TaW. Another thing the cursor position seems to change outside of my area. Do you see any problem on this if clause.         if (((Xm >= current.X) && (Xm <= (current.X + current.Width))) && ((Ym >= current.Y) && (Ym <= (current.Y + current.Width))))
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            }

Comment: Break is a good option as well. - (Ym <= (current.Y + current.Width)) this ought to be Height, right? Rectangle has useful functions like Contains(Point) and Intersects(Rectangle). Do try to use these to make the code more readable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`Rectangle.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.contains%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The actual error is in the else clause. Delete it and set a flag in the if; check this after the loop..:

```
    bool flag = false;
    foreach (RectangleF rec in allRectangles)
    {
        if (rec.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

   if (!flag)     this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

Comment: Thank you again for Rectangle.Contains

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the issue is that you are setting the cursor over and over again in your loop. Define a variable and check after the loop if it has changed. In addition you can leave the loop with a `break;` if you have found an overlap with a rectangle. Also as mentioned by @TaW in his answer the Rectangle.Contains makes the whole thing easier.

```
void MouseChanger(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    RectangleF[] allRectangles = new RectangleF[aListDrawings.Count];
    aListDrawings.CopyTo(allRectangles);

    if (allRectangles.Length == 0)
        return;
    RectangleF currentSelected = RectangleF.Empty;
    var overlap = false;

    foreach (RectangleF rec in allRectangles)
    {

        float Xm = e.X;
        float Ym = e.Y;
        RectangleF current = GetOffsetRectangle(rec);

        if (((Xm >= current.X) && (Xm <= (current.X + current.Width))) && ((Ym >= current.Y) && (Ym <= (current.Y + current.Width))))
        {
            overlapse=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    this.Cursor = overlapse ? Cursors.Hand : Cursors.Default;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use return / break to stop the loop, else it keep checking. That is the reason it is working for last one and not working for other, because the iteration continue and else condition execute.

```
if (((Xm >= current.X) && (Xm <= (current.X + current.Width))) && ((Ym >= current.Y) && (Ym <= (current.Y + current.Width))))
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
```